# how to extract json reponse returned by google api in WindowsPhone application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

I am trying to extract the response returned by google map api.I heard of Json.NET. But the reference I am trying to add to windows phone application from the location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\` is not working.

I tried to find the same from location `C:\Program Filesx86\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71`. But still not able to find the Json.NET reference in windows phone .net

Which reference i need to add to work with datacontractjsonserializer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at link .Thanks. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ronak/archive/2011/07/18/datacontractjsonserializer-and-windows-phone-7.aspx